# Scroll Iframe up & down from parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll

Okay, this is probably one of the most asked questions on stackoverflow, but I can't find one single crossbrowser solution for that :(

I have a page, with an iframe inside. I need to control the scrolling up & down of this iframe, from the parent page.

I have this code, with arrows that controls the up & down of my parent page, but does anyone know how can I control the iframe scrolling instead? Thank you so much in advance!

I made a JSFiddle to make easier to see my problem http://jsfiddle.net/misskathryn/8hNJe/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/misskathryn/8hNJe/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know of, that works across all browsers and is not derailed by the user clicking on "open in new tab" is this:

- in the parent, have a pair of variables, that store scrollup/scrolldown functions (or a single scrollto, or whatever fits your needs)
- In the child, use `window.parent` and on failure `opener` to store child-local functions into these, that do the real scrolling
- In the parent, use those variables to initiate the scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.scrollTo(x, y);
```

I think this would help

Comment: would you tell me where in my code should I add this part? thank you so much

Comment: suppose you create a button with onclick event, call that function